# Как запустить несколько fcgi программ для прослушивания одного порта

Tags: fastcgi

Установлен nginx, libfcgi, spawn-fcgi.

Создал 2 fcgi программы генерирующие веб-страницу. Программы работают, nginx перенаправляет запрос программе.

Я же хочу запускать несколько fcgi программ, но может работать только одна, что странно. 1 веб страница = 1 fcgi программа.

Запускаю так:

```
#!/bin/bash

cur_dir=$(pwd)

spawn-fcgi -p 8000 $cur_dir/fcgi/main.fcgi

spawn-fcgi -p 8000 $cur_dir/fcgi/main2.fcgi

$SHELL
```

Вывод:

```
spawn-fcgi: child spawned successfully: PID: 18757

spawn-fcgi: bind failed: Address already in use

jordan@jordan-aspirea31523:~/Desktop/web_cpp$
```

Как запустить несколько fcgi программ?

Comment: А как вы предполагаете определять, какая программа должна обрабатывать тот или иной запрос, если бы они теоретически работали на одном и том же порту?

Comment: пускай слушают разные порты, а задачи между ними распределяет nginx через upstream

Answer (score 2):

Для TCP вы не можете повесить больше одной программы на порт. Как вы и указали выше, только 1 порт - 1 программа.

Но вы можете создать главный процесс, который слушает желаемый вами порт и в зависимости от запросов уже разделяет их.

Или как написал товарищ @nörbörnën,

> пускай слушают разные порты, а задачи между ними распределяет nginx через upstream